# how to retain values in a sas dataset?

Tags: sas, retain

I have the following dataset

```
data have;
input pop$  district$ racemajor$;
cards;
    color   Aberdeen    .
    white   Aberdeen    .
    Black   Aberdeen    .
    Asian   Aberdeen    .
    Black   Adelaid  Yes
    Color   Adelaid     .
    white   Adelaid     .
    Asian   Adelaid     .
    White   Bellvill    .
    black   Bellvill    .
    Asian   Bellvill    .
;
run;
```

Basically I want to drag the value `'Yes'` if racemajor is 'Yes' for the corresponding district so that it looks like the following

```
data want;
    color   Aberdeen    .
    white   Aberdeen    .
    Black   Aberdeen    .
    Asian   Aberdeen    .
    Black   Adelaid     Yes
    Color   Adelaid     Yes
    white   Adelaid     Yes
    Asian   Adelaid     Yes
    White   Bellvill    .
    black   Bellvill    .
    Asian   Bellvill    .
```

I know that I can use the `first.` and `retain` statement to do this, and I tried the following. However, it does not seem to work.

```
data want;
set have;
if first.district and racemajor='Yes';
retain racemajor;
run;
```

Comment: Why doesn't the last Adelaid have a YES?

Comment: I suspect it's just a typo if not we can add an if.last

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, although to be safe you should sort the data on district

```
data NEW;
drop test;
SET HAVE;
by district;
retain test;
if first.district then test = racemajor;
racemajor=test;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is good example for the update trick, where the master is empty and you output all obs.

```
data have;
   input (pop district racemajor) ($);
   cards;
    color   Aberdeen    .
    white   Aberdeen    .
    Black   Aberdeen    .
    Asian   Aberdeen    .
    Black   Adelaid  Yes
    Color   Adelaid     .
    white   Adelaid     .
    Asian   Adelaid     .
    White   Bellvill    .
    black   Bellvill    .
    Asian   Bellvill    .
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data want;
   update have(obs=0) have;
   by district;
   output;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```